# Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_player' in base 'Viewport'

Tags: gdscript, s

I run the script

```
func search():
    var pl = get_parent().get_parent().get_player()
```

and I get the error Non-existent function 'get_player' in the base 'Viewport'.

what to do?

I have to get from the parent node

```
func get_player():
return $Player
```

but an error comes out Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_player' in base 'Viewport'.

Comment: Are you sure you want the parent of the parent (`get_parent().get_parent()`)? How does your scene tree look like? How are the `Node`s with these scripts attached positioned relative to each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what your parent nodes are,do a print(get_parent().name) that way you will get to the node you suppose.

If your parent node has a child node "player" do:
get_parent().get_parent().get_node("player")

Would be helpful if you would post a picture of your scene,if you want an accurate answer